# Regex to extract attributes

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the sub-strings form an file.but i am only able to get the one sub-string but unable to get eh second one .

Here is the line example :

```
<testPoolResult name="Pool" loop="1" currency="false" randomized="false" startTime="01.01.70_02:10:059""01.01.70_02:11:000" duration="0">

<testCase name="Test" status="SUCCESS" iteration="1" startTime="01.01.70_02:10:059" endTime="01.01.70_02:10:059" duration="0">

<testAction name="pend" status="SUCCESS" iteration="1" startTime="01.01.70_02:10:059" endTime="01.01.70_02:10:059" duration="0"/>
```

I need to parse the line which is having `testCase` and extract the name of the test and status of the test.

here is my code :

```
use warnings;
open( my $fh, "<", "test.txt" ) or die "can not open the file $! \n";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /testCase\s+name[=""](.+?)\s+status[=""](.+?)/x ) {
        print $1. " " . $2 . "\n";
    }
}
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: If you're parsing XML use an XML parser such as XML::Twig https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig

Comment: its bit crude way`if($line =~ /testCase\s+name\=\"(.*?)\"\s+status\=\"(.*?)\"/i)
{
 print $1,$2;
 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
if($line =~ /testCase\s+name[=""](.+?)\s+status[=""](.+?)/x)
```

with

```
if ($line =~ /testCase\s+name="(.+?)"\s+status="(.+?)"/x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you processing an XML file? Use a proper parser, e.g. [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open test.xml ;
for //testCase echo @name @status ;
```